# Can't display images on localhost

Tags: permissions, apache2, php, mysql, gedit

I installed Apache2, MySQL, and PHP on Ubuntu.

After creating my `test.php` file I can't see the pictures on this file. Also, I can't save files or images directly in the `/var/www/html` folder. I have use Gedit to save in the `/var/www/html` folder. However, even with Gedit I can't display images in my `test.php` file.

The contents of the test.php file is:

```
<?php echo '<img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" >'; ?>
```

It must be a permissions issue.

Comment: What do you mean by showing images in a PHP file? That doesn't make sense to me. Could you [edit] the question to clarify? Perhaps include the content of your `test.php`.

Comment: in my test.php file i have a simple php code  echo '<img src = ....> but it doesnt let me view the image, i can echo out text in the test.php file. I had to use gedit to actually beeing able to move test.php into the var/www/html folder

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the contents of `ls /var/www/html`

Comment: index.html  test.php

Answer (score 0):

In general there is lack of details about your LAMP and Ubuntu version.

Lets assume that you have ran into group permissions issue involving Apache2 etc.

The default Apache group in Ubuntu is www-data. To solve the problem, a user needed to be added to the www-data group. 
I'll use the username "bobby" for the examples below.

**Add an existing user to the www-data group:**

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G www-data bobby
```

To verify, use the groups command (collection of groups in results may be different):

```
$ groups bobby
bobby: adm bobby cdrom sudo dip www-data plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

Comment: i used ubuntu before, i reinstalled it a few days ago, before i didnt have those permission issues, how come i haave them now?? the only user on my laptop is me and i have now/had before only 1 user  signed up and stil everything worked

Comment: i tried sudo usermod -a -G www-data bobby and it gave me the message user booby doesnt exist

Comment: i tried that above command with my username and it didnt do anything

Comment: Groda Michl, please provide your code example from your test.php file

Comment: <?php  echo '<img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" >';  ?>

Comment: @GrodaMichl you won't get any output back from the usermod command if it's successful. Log out, and then back in to reload the groups for your user, then run the `groups` command in a terminal as your current user. It should have `www-data` added to it.

Comment: it didnt do anything

Answer (score 0):

try to execute this:

```
cd /var/www && sudo chown -R `whoami`:`whoami`
```

If you do this, then you will be able to modify the files under /var/www because the files will belong to you and your personal group. The -R runs the command recursively - it runs on the current file (the directory) and all the files in and under the directory

Comment: Instead of changing the ownership to your user, it's better to add your current user to the `www-data` group.

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0):

For just test with your LAMP server, use `phpinfo` function is a good idea for you.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Put the code above with root permission in `test.php` file with `sudo vim test.php`. and guest to learn [howto use vim editor](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_06_02.html) on a linux system.

Comment: i cant save phpinfo code in my test.php, vim not found

Comment: install vim `sudo apt-get install vim` or just use echo with root `sudo -s` then `echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > test.php`